# main.c:(.text+0x30): undefined reference to `reciprocal'

Tags: c++, c, gcc

I was trying the first program of Advance Linux Programming. Some other guys also felt this problem but reading those thread are not helping me. I tried also those methods but my problem is still there. Please help me.

Here is main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "reciprocal.hpp"

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int i;
    i = atoi(argv[1]);
    printf("The reciprocal of %d is %g\n", i, reciprocal(i));
    return 0;
}
```

Listing reciprocal.cpp

```
#include <cassert>
#include "reciprocal.hpp"

using namespace std;


    double reciprocal(int i) {
        //I should not be Zero
        assert(i != 0);
         return 1.0/i;
    }
```

Listing reciprocal.hpp

```
#ifdef _cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

  extern double reciprocal (int i);

#ifdef _cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Listing Makefile:

```
reciprocal: main.o reciprocal.o
    g++ $(CFLAGS) -o reciprocal main.o reciprocal.o

main.o: main.c reciprocal.hpp
    gcc $(CFLAGS) -c main.c -I ../include

reciprocal.o: reciprocal.cpp reciprocal.hpp
    g++ $(CFLAGS) -c reciprocal.cpp -I ../include

clean:
    rm -f *.o reciprocal
```

The error is:

```
rajat$ make
gcc  -c main.c -I ../include
g++  -c reciprocal.cpp -I ../include
g++  -o reciprocal main.o reciprocal.o
main.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x30): undefined reference to `reciprocal'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [reciprocal] Error 1
```

Comment: why not main.cpp? edit: Also I am not sure if function should be marked as extern, I think only variables can be preceded by that keyword

Comment: I also marked the function as extern "C", as explained in other thread, but the problem did not resolved.

Comment: `_cplusplus` is not correct. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/35fd78f99bdb6fee

Comment: `#ifdef __cplusplus`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have `__cplusplus` (the [proper macro definition](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html)) not `_cplusplus` in your macro.

---

How to debug: find the undefined `reciprocal` in `main.o`:

```
nm main.o | grep reciprocal
                 U reciprocal
```

And look for it in your `reciprocal.o`:

- With `__cplusplus`:

  ```
  $ nm reciprocal.o | grep reciprocal
  0000000000000000 T reciprocal
  0000000000000020 r _ZZ10reciprocalE19__PRETTY_FUNCTION__
  ```
- Without (with `_cplusplus` as your wrote it):

  ```
  $ nm reciprocal.o | grep reciprocal
  0000000000000000 T _Z10reciprocali
  0000000000000020 r _ZZ10reciprocaliE19__PRETTY_FUNCTION__
  ```